# how to perform a scheduled task in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How do we perform a repetitive task (once a day for example) in sailsjs. I need to analyze the records in my database, and I want to do it all at once so the user doesn't have to wait each time they update their records.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either roll out your own solution using libraries like [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue), or [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), or [node-cron](http://merencia.com/node-cron/), or you can use something like [`sails-hook-schedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-schedule)